# Fast reading of gzip (text file) using io.BufferedReader in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, bufferedreader

I'm trying to efficiently read in, and parse, a compressed text file using the gzip module. This [link](https://gist.github.com/theJollySin/6eeda4a44db830a35365503178f88788) suggests wrapping the gzip file object with `io.BufferedReader`, like so:

```
import gzip, io
gz = gzip.open(in_path, 'rb')
f = io.BufferedReader(gz)
     for line in f.readlines():
         # do stuff
gz.close()
```

To do this in Python 3, I think `gzip` must be called with `mode='rb'`. So the result is that `line` is a binary string. However, I need `line` to be a text/ascii string. Is there a more efficient way to read in the file as a text string using `BufferedReader`, or will I have to decode `line` inside the for loop?

Comment: Side-note: Don't do `for line in f.readlines():`. That needlessly eagerly slurps the file into a `list` of lines immediately, iterates the `list`, then discards it. It means you need memory proportionate to the file's (uncompressed) size for no reason. Just do `for line in f:`, and get the lines lazily, on demand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `io.TextIOWrapper` to seamlessly wrap a binary stream to a text stream instead:

```
f = io.TextIOWrapper(gz)
```

Or as @ShadowRanger pointed out, you can simply open the gzip file in text mode instead, so that the `gzip` module will apply the `io.TextIOWrapper` wrapper for you:

```
for line in gzip.open(in_path, 'rt'):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Except you don't even need to do that explicitly, since you can just pass the mode a `'rt'` (and optionally pass a specified `encoding`), which will have `gzip.open` do all the wrapping work for you.

Comment: Indeed I forgot about it. Updated accordingly then. Thanks.